# Loading different integrations from properties file

Tags: java, selenium, jvm, testng, properties-file

I am working on a project for finals at my Uni, and I am having a particular problem. I am testing how certain Website works in localhost using TestNG and Selenium. Now, I have different integrations, meaning it uses different databases configured in properties file. I was hoping I could pass parameters in JVM, or command line saying for example "integration1" and It would catch that field from property file. Only thing I found online is regarding Spring profiles, but that is not helpful since it's a normal java project. Here is a code:

default.properties

```
db_driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_path = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dana?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

user.properties (It checks if certain field exists in user.properties file, and if it does it uses that one instead of default, useful for other members on a team, since each configuration is different)

```
db_driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_path_elixir = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elixir?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
db_path_dana = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dana?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
#db_path - actual path which will be used if user passes "dana" or "elixir" as arguments
#my logic would be something like db_path = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ + ${integration} + ?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Those property files are configured in ConfigurationService class

ConfigurationService.java

```
...
private String getProperty(String key) {
    if (userProperties.containsKey(key)) {
        return userProperties.getProperty(key);
    }
    return defaultProperties.getProperty(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your ConfigurationService as follows and pass property as `java -Dkey=value` from command line.

```
private String getProperty(String key){
    String value = null;
    if (System.getProperties().contains(key))
        value = System.getProperty(key);
    else if (userProperties.containsKey(key))
        value = userProperties.getProperty(key);
    else
        value = defaultProperties.getProperty(key);
}
```

You can also initialize your ConfigurationService instance as below

```
Properties properties;
public void init(){
 properties.putAll(defaultProperties);
 properties.putAll(userProperties);
 properties.putAll(System.getProperties());
}
```

then modify your getProperty method as below

```
private String getProperty(String key){
        return properties.getProperty(key);
}
```

Here sequence of `putAll` call is important. When you put same key-value again the earlier value is overwritten.